# Who do B'nei Noach turn to for psak?

Tags: gentiles, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, noachide-laws, noahidism

My understanding is that there are a few organized groups of non-Jews who strive to follow the Noahide laws. Just like Jews, B'nei Noach might have situations where the correct action to take is unclear. When Jews have such a problem, they ask a competent halachic authority their question. Presumably, there must be an equivalent type of "posek" who can answer the questions of the non-Jews and determine what their halacha is.

Are there any people who are known as prominent poskim for non-Jews? Are these poskim rabbis or are they non-Jews?

Comment: Or perhaps they are non Jewish rabbis?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30418/may-a-ben-noach-ask-a-non-jew-for-psak?rq=1

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92328

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of Rabbis, mostly Chabad, involved in teaching Bnei Noach and answering their halachic questions. One of the more prominent ones is Rabbi Yaakov Rogalsky, co-author of [Path of the Righteous Gentile](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/087306433X). Another is [Rabbi Chaim Richman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Richman).

Answer (score 1):

Rav Uri Sherky (Cherki) recently published a kitzur shulkhan arukh for B'nei Noach, with approbations of several well-known and widely respected poskim. Inter alia, Rav Cherki is one of the Jewish leaders of the B'nei Noach group one can find at https://noahideworldcenter.org/