# Where can a gentile seek guidance?

Tags: gentiles, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, noachide-laws

Jews have rabbanim to provide them with guidance. What about gentiles? Where can they go to seek guidance when they are unsure of how to conduct themselves?

While one could argue that the Noachide laws are fairly straightforward, there are still potentially many situations where a gentile may find themselves unsure of how to act. Where can they seek guidance? Who can they ask for advice? It is forbidden for them to learn Torah, so from where can we receive instruction?

It is great that we have this resource on Stack Exchange, but as the side bar on this site says, it is still no substitute for a rabbi. Where can an individual gentile go to seek personalized, professional advice such as the kind that a rabbi would provide to a Jew to ensure that they conduct themselves in accordance to HaShem's will?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30404

Comment: @msh210 Are you not considering this a duplicate because it is asking about guidance more general than _p'sak_? Otherwise it seems to me to be covered by those other 2 questions.

Comment: @WAF, precisely.

Comment: A non-Jew can go to a rabbi too for questions about Noahide practice.